# Django Admin Inlines error "MultipleObjectsReturned at"

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a many-to-many relationship connecting 3 models.
like this:

```
    ucn-\
         \
          |-ucn2tipoveg   Many to many!
         /
Tipoveg-/
```

It works but when i try to edit an entry on my django admin it returns this error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /admin/accounts/ucs/211/change/

get() returned more than one Ucn2Tipoveg -- it returned 3!
```

models.py:

```
class Tipoveg(models.Model):
    tipoveg_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nometipoveg = models.CharField(db_column='nomeTipoVeg',blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False

class Ucs(models.Model):
    ucn_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,db_column='ucn_id')
    nome = models.CharField(verbose_name="nome",max_length=255, blank=True, 
    tipo = models.ManyToManyField(Tipoveg, through='Ucn2Tipoveg')
    class Meta:
        managed = False

def get_default_ucn():
    return Ucn2Tipoveg.objects.latest('ucn2tipovegid').ucn2tipovegid+1

class Ucn2Tipoveg(models.Model):
    ucn= models.ForeignKey(Ucs, models.DO_NOTHING,db_column='ucn_id')
    tipoveg = models.ForeignKey(Tipoveg, models.DO_NOTHING)
    ucn2tipovegid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,default=get_default_ucn)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        unique_together = (('ucn_id', 'tipoveg'),)
```

Comment: I see your models have `managed = False`. Are you sure the unique constraints are there on the database tables and there aren't actually multiple values for the same relation?

Comment: @Abdul For sure!Everything is working except editing